# Displaying on label

Tags: objective-c

I want to display some text means name of any source file with extension in a label. But the width is fixed and if the name is more than the width I want the name to be displayed like "Women Que...nnaire.jpg". Is it possible to display like this . If possible please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set following in your label object:

```
adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=NO;
lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
numberOfLines=1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul de Lange.This is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer;

Set :

lablel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

Set Minimum font size of text;

lablel.minimumFontSize=10;// depends on you. How small font you want!

Answer (score -1):

auto adjust size from label using this property using--

`sizeToFit`